# c# checklistbox check if item is selected

Tags: c#, if-statement, selecteditem, checklistbox

It my sound trivial but I can't get around. How do I know if item in checklistbox is selected ? I've got checklistbox with 3 items and I'd like to do some 'if then' statements. Basically ,if chkbox1.Checked Items 'ABC' is selected / checked then..

Thanks

Comment: selected or checked? there is a small (or big) difference

Comment: Sorry I meant 'checked'

Comment: A, can you post some code as well? as for now it's not totally clear what you mean.

Comment: @pawel what about searching **"C# checklistbox"** in google and just read some sample code at MSDN site? As a proggramer I Recommend you to learn by searching the internet - its free and easy.

Answer (score 1):

CheckedListBox contains CheckedItems property. You can get all checked items from this collection. Read here: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

got this solved by using

```
GetItemCheckState(0) == CheckState.Checked
```

and using 0 first item ,1 second item etc.